# XNA tiling a sprite with a camera.viewmatrix in the Draw method

Tags: xna, c#, game-design, software-engineering

I'm looking for help fixing a small problem that I have with my XNA game project.

I currently have:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
            null, null, null, null, camera.ViewMatrix);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Stone, TestPosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Person, playerPosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
```

and

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred,
              null, SamplerState.LinearWrap, null, null);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Grass, grassPosition,
             new Rectangle(0, 0, Grass.Width * 60, Grass.Height * 1),
             Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Stone, StonePosition,
             new Rectangle(0, 0, Stone.Width * 60, Stone.Height * 10),
             Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();
```

I am looking to combine these two spriteBatch so that the stone and grass in the second spriteBatch will be affected by the viewmatrix.

I have tried:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
                SamplerState.LinearWrap, null, null, null, camera.ViewMatrix);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Grass, grassPosition,
                 new Rectangle(0, 0, Grass.Width * 60, Grass.Height * 1),
                 Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Stone, StonePosition,
                 new Rectangle(0, 0, Stone.Width * 60, Stone.Height * 10),
                 Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Stone, TestPosition, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Person, playerPosition, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
```

However when I go to run the code, I get the following error:

XNA Framework Reach profile requires TextureAddressMode to be Clamp when using texture sizes that are not powers of two.

I hope that someone can help me achieve this,
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that if you are using textures that are not powers of 2 (128x128, 256x256, etc), that you must set the `SamplerState` parameter of `SpriteBatch.Begin` to `SamplerState.LinearClamp` instead of `SamplerState.LinearWrap`.

Judging from your code it looks like `Grass` and `Stone` are powers of 2, but the `Person` is not.

To fix the problem you'll need to either change the `Person` texture to a power of two, use `SamplerState.LinearClamp` for everything you listed, or draw the `Person` texture with its own `SpriteBatch.Begin` and `End` using `Sampler.LinearClamp` and the rest that are powers of two using `LinearWrap`.

Comment: Or change from Reach to HiDef profile in the property settings of the project.

Comment: Thanks, it's working great and thank you for your fast response.